# Shell script to print the number of hours and minutes a user has been logged on?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a shell script using the date and who commands to print how the number of hours and minutes a user has been logged in. I can assume it is less than 24 hours. How would I do this?

I would think I would somehow extract the time from the date command and from the who command and somehow subtract them, but I'm not sure how I would implement that.

Comment: users can log in more than once; do you want the most recent login, or the oldest?  (what are you actually trying to accomplish here?)

Comment: and... http://WhatHaveYouTried.com ... Stackoverflow is about helping people with specific problem with code, .... what does your code look like? Good luck.

Comment: You might want to check out the `last` command: `last $username`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

export LANG=C

date_string=$(
    who |
    sort -k3M -k4n |
    awk '{if ($1 ~ user) {print $3, $4, $5;exit}}' user="$1"
)
diff_seconds_between_date_and_now=$((
    $(date +%s) - $(date -d "$date_string" +%s)
))
printf "%s %s\n" "$((diff_seconds_between_date_and_now/3600)) hours" \
    "$((diff_seconds_between_date_and_now%3600/60)) minutes"
```

I takes the oldest line whith the specified user :

Usage :

```
$ bash script.bash <USERNAME>
```

Sample output :

```
$ bash script.bash sputnick
528 hours 6 minutes
```

Comment: I get wrong order in the sorting, if I run `env LANG=C who`, the date is outputted as `Feb 18 18:46`, `sort -k3M -k4n` should fix this. Also awk would need to print three fields: `print $3" "$4" "$5`. This is on Debian Linux with GNU coreutils.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But also the double quoted spaces are important in awk, otherwise `Feb 18 18:46` will be printed as `Feb1818:46`.